# Count interval using function cut

Tags: r

I want to count numbers in function of intervals pre-defined.
for example:

```
Vect<-c(2,5,9,11)
interval<-cut(Vect,c(0,3,5,7,12))
interval<-as.data.frame(interval)
count_interval<-interval%>%group_by(interval)%>%summarise(n=n())
```

count_interval shows me :

```
  interval     n
  <fct>    <int>
1 (0,3]        1
2 (3,5]        1
3 (7,12]       2
```

but i want to my code detect that there is an interval missing and add automatically a row like following dataframe:

```
  interval     n
  <fct>    <int>
1 (0,3]        1
2 (3,5]        1
3 (5,7]        0
4 (7,12]       2
```

How could I get that? Thanks for you help.

Comment: Use `.drop = FALSE` in `group_by`.

Comment: @RonakShah I tried it, but i doesn't work: ``` count_interval<-interval%>%group_by(interval,.drop=FALSE)%>%summarise(n=n())```

Comment: How do you even get the output that you have showed? `interval` is a vector and not a dataframe, when I do `interval%>%group_by(interval)%>%summarise(n=n())` it gives an error to me `Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "factor"`

Comment: you re right, in this example,  i forgot to precise that i transformed it into a dataframe before ```group_by```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.drop = FALSE` to include factor levels which are empty.

```
library(dplyr)
interval%>% group_by(interval, .drop = FALSE) %>% summarise(n=n())

# A tibble: 4 x 2
#  interval     n
#  <fct>    <int>
#1 (0,3]        1
#2 (3,5]        1
#3 (5,7]        0
#4 (7,12]       2
```

Alternately, you can also use `count`

```
interval%>% count(interval, .drop = FALSE)
```

Note that some of these functions are also present in `plyr` library, so if you have that library loaded these functions might mask them. In such case, restart R and load only `dplyr` library or explicitly mention `dplyr::summarise` and `dplyr::count`.

Comment: unfortunate, i tried : ```interval%>% group_by(interval, .drop = FALSE) %>% dplyr::summarise(n=n())``` , it gives me: ```   interval .drop     n
  <fct>    <lgl> <int>
1 (0,3]    FALSE     1
2 (3,5]    FALSE     1
3 (7,12]   FALSE     2 ```

Comment: ```group_by``` consideres ```.drop``` like new column  (sorry , I don't know why my table does not show correctly

Comment: It works fine for me. What is your `packageVersion('dplyr')` ? I have `0.8.3`. Are you using the same example as in your post ?

Comment: ```0.7.8``` , I have to update it with install.package

Comment: Yes, please update the package. I guess `.drop` was introduced in later versions hence you get it as a new column.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `table` to *count the number in each group*.

```
table(interval)
#interval
# (0,3]  (3,5]  (5,7] (7,12] 
#     1      1      0      2
```

and in case you need it as a `data.frame` cast it to it using `as.data.frame`.

```
as.data.frame(table(interval))
#  interval Freq
#1    (0,3]    1
#2    (3,5]    1
#3    (5,7]    0
#4   (7,12]    2
```

In case you want the *maximum per group* you can use `aggregate`:

```
data<-data.frame(x1=Vect,x2=cut(Vect,c(0,3,5,7,12)))
aggregate(x1~., data, max, drop = FALSE)
#      x2 x1
#1  (0,3]  2
#2  (3,5]  5
#3  (5,7] NA
#4 (7,12] 11
```

Comment: thank you, but I had to transform it to a dataframe. is there another way directly to get the result?

Comment: @DDchen Wrap the answer into a function, `fun <- function(x) as.data.frame(table(x));fun(interval)`.

Comment: thank you , my example is a simple way to illustrate my issue. but if I want to do more complicate operations in ```summarise``` , ```table``` function would not be enough

Comment: @DDchen What complicate operations would you like to do?

Comment: @GKi , if I have ```data<-data.frame(x1=Vect,x2=cut(Vect,c(0,3,5,7,12)))``` then I would like to group by x2 then take the maximum of x1.  and the final base still contains a row with (5,7]  indicating NA for the maximum

Comment: @DDchen For this you can use `aggregate` - see the update.